# Form Wizard Next Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the next button.  It seems that the button didn't work. The design is okay and I think it has something to do with the `javascript` and I don't know where since I am still practice front-end.
I tried to do some changes from the javascript and css for hoping it would work but nothing happen a miracle.  Does anyone have any idea why is this happening? The original code is came from this link:

> https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/rvPDr

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Initialize tooltips
  $('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();

  //Wizard
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {

    var $target = $(e.target);

    if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false;
    }
  });

  $(".next-step").click(function(e) {

    var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
    $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
    nextTab($active);

  });
  $(".prev-step").click(function(e) {

    var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
    prevTab($active);

  });
});

function nextTab(elem) {
  $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}

function prevTab(elem) {
  $(elem).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
```

```css
.wizard {
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.wizard>div.wizard-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.connecting-line {
  height: 2px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.wizard .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.wizard .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  color: #555555;
  cursor: default;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

span.round-tab {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

span.round-tab i {
  color: #555555;
}

.wizard li.active span.round-tab {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #5bc0de;
}

.wizard li.active span.round-tab i {
  color: #5bc0de;
}

span.round-tab:hover {
  color: #333;
  border: 2px solid #333;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs>li {
  width: 25%;
}

.wizard li:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 46%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.wizard li.active:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 46%;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs>li a {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs>li a:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.wizard .tab-pane {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.wizard h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media( max-width: 585px) {
  .wizard {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto !important;
  }
  span.round-tab {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  .wizard .nav-tabs>li a {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  .wizard li.active:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section>
      <div class="wizard">
        <div class="wizard-inner">
          <div class="connecting-line"></div>
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
              <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
                <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
              <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
              <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
                                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
              <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Complete">
                <span class="round-tab">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <form role="form">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
              <h3>Step 1</h3>
              <p>This is step 1</p>
              <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
              <h3>Step 2</h3>
              <p>This is step 2</p>
              <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3">
              <h3>Step 3</h3>
              <p>This is step 3</p>
              <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-step">Skip</button></li>
                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="complete">
              <h3>Complete</h3>
              <p>You have successfully completed all steps.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AbhishekPandey hmp... thats weird. did I missed any reference? maybe asp.net core missed some reference.  if so what are the relevant reference for this?

Comment: Make sure `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` flies are included.

Comment: Thank you so much! it was jquery.min.js not installed in my project.  Thanks for this!